# Unable to restart lsyncd after killing it

Tags: rsync, services

I noticed that I was not getting new backups on our DR, so I took a look and saw that `lsyncd` was stuck on the server that sends to the DR via `lsyncd`. Our backup logs showed endless errors of "Waiting for child process to terminate." I eventually killed the lsyncd tasks since they were stuck and have since been unable to restart lsyncd. The backup to DR is configured through `/etc/lsyncd.conf`.

When I run status on lsyncd after I run

```
systemctl start lsyncd.service
```

I get the following error:

```
[root@backupsteve bin]# systemctl status lsyncd.service
● lsyncd.service - Live Syncing (Mirror) Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/lsyncd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead)

Apr  3 17:22:19 backupsteve systemd: Started Live Syncing (Mirror) 
Daemon.
Apr  3 17:22:19 backupsteve systemd: Starting Live Syncing (Mirror) Daemon...
Apr  3 17:22:19 backupsteve sh: Error: failure getting absolute path of [/usr/local/cherbles/archive/plause/backups/dr551-prod/sftpdrop2/latestbackup/]
Apr  3 17:22:19 backupsteve sh: Error: Cannot access source directory: /usr/local/cherbles/archive/plause/backups/dr551-prod/sftpdrop2/latestbackup/
```

I am able to browse to the `../dr551-prod/sftpdrop2/latestbackup` just fine. 
 and see the backups. It is just a link to the latest backup folder. This particular backup (dr551-prod) entry in the `.conf` file is towards the middle, but it errors on this one immediately for some reason. There are probably 20 servers in front of this. I do not have any instances of `lsyncd` running and I have stop/started it a good bit of times.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with part of my .conf file. There was an error in the code so each time it tried to start it failed trying to go to a directory that didn't exist.  Maybe that will help yall!